# Samba Sharing Not Work Via of VPN

Tags: networking, server, samba, vpn

I have an image to explain this weird situation;

[image: problem-on-Samba-sharing]

Note: if you cannot see picture above, please use this link, [problem-on-Samba-sharing](https://github.com/zhongxiang117/codeDump/blob/master/imageTrashBin/pain-on-samba-share.jpg)

The basic rule is, for any campus devices, they can only be connected by school internet, therefore, if any devices are outside but want to link to device inside, they have to via of VPN, its brand is Pulse Secure.

By referring the picture, we will know that everything is perfect fine inside campus and other devices outside the campus through VPN.

However, it only refuses to work on my school Desktop when I am using home Desktop & laptop link to.

I have already completely removed Samba and clean installed it once, but the problem persists.

The kernel for my host Desktop is;

```
Linux 5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My laptop is windows 10, version `10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363`, its IP configuration is;

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : hsd1.fl.comcast.net.
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2601:58a:8302:9340:9df1:3231:b9:23fc
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : 2601:58a:8302:9340:90f2:2207:ddda:195a
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9df1:3231:b9:23fc%30
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.10
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::1ad6:c7ff:fee8:e3a7%30
                                       192.168.1.1
```

Can anyone please shed any lights or teach me anythings about IP-VPN knowledge? I will greatly appreciate it!

### Reason & Solution

For anyone happens to find this page, this problem is caused by my Modem, which for unknown reasons blocked VPN file sharing. Reset it, then everything becomes normal.

It works well before I bridged it with a more powerful 5G Modem then switched back to it.

Honestly, I still cannot understand that should it have any fundamental differences after doing a round step: Itself --> Itself with 5G Modem --> Itself?

Answer (score 0):

Does the Samba server responds if you ping it? Some old Samba servers requires on your Windows workstation that smb 1.0 has to be installed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. The Samba server is installed in my Windows. The ping when outside the campus does not work. But two things need to be sure are that, everything works perfect fine for other devices except my school Desktop, and also, the settings for both my client (laptop) and host are good inside campus. So I guess it must have some thing in my school Desktop that blocked my ISP, that is why I post my IP configuration in here. Do you have any other suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Besides, I also fell confused is that how can my school Desktop only not work on my home network (please again have a look on my plot)? Does Samba have ability to check and verify the coming request is from VPN or real IP address? It is so weird and abnormal.